# Using Minconda creates new Python install

Tags: python, miniconda

Was trying to resolve a HDF5 mismatch error by uninstalling the parent package yt  ie

```
  PIP uninstall yt
```

and then reinstalling using Miniconda

```
  conda install yt
```

If I simply open a terminal and do an
     import yt

no problem!
However, from with my application when I open a Python shell and do an 
    import yt
I get an error

```
'ImportError: No module named yt'
```

So I think the error is either my application does not know the path to yt,
or
When I installed Miniconda it installed its own version of Python.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda always creates a python **virtual environment** and so it installs packages into this [environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).
Thus your installation lives only inside of this environment.

If you want to use the packages conda installed, then you have to use conda's bash shell, or use some other tools inside of conda within the given environment.

If you have a python code, what you want to run with `yt` - importing it, then you have to run it inside of the conda environment where you installed `yt`.

You can do it e.g. with starting `anaconda-navigator`, choose `Environments`, click on the green solid arrow and choose any options to run your application.

Alternatively you can directly **activate** conda's virtualenv via:

On **Windows**, in your Anaconda Prompt, run:

```
activate myenv
```

On **macOS** and **Linux**, in your Terminal Window, run:

```
source activate myenv
```

Then you can start your application in this environment as normal.

**UPDATE:**

According to darthbith, since conda 4.4, the command is

```
conda activate myenv
```

on all platforms.

Comment: Since conda 4.4, the command is `conda activate myenv` on all platforms

Comment: @darthbith thank for spotting, I made an update and gave an up. :)